# native skype calls recoder without transcoding

Tags: skype

is there a Skype calls recorder that grabs the native audio stream directly (without transcoding)?
This should be the best choice for audio quality/disk usage.

EDIT: i guess the right tool for the job is Wireshark, any guide for that?

Comment: How do you mean, without transcoding? The audio from the remote side will always be transcoded when it arrives at your client. Or do you just mean a recorder that saves uncompressed files?

Comment: I mean grabbing the audio in the native Skype codec (SILK currently)